# Vertical centering of text within a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table defined as:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3.0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ | c | p{12.5cm} |}
            \hline
            \textbf{Item 1} & Long description of item 1 \\
            \hline
            % ... (etc)
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

I want the text in the first column to be both vertically and horizontally aligned. Given the code above, the text is only horizontally aligned. I have tried fixing this by changing the column alignment/width specifier from 'c' to 'm{2.5cm}', but to no avail.

How do I make the column centered both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: With this setting, the "Item 1" will be aligned to the first line in column 2; if you want it to be vertically centered with respect to the second column, use `m{12.5cm}` for the *second* column specifier.

Comment: and don't forget to load package `array` ...

Comment: @egreg Thanks, your suggestion got it working.

Comment: @Herbert: Josh is already using `\extrarowheight`, but I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: it's been said many times before ... rather than use the `center` environment, it's better to use `\centering` within a float.

Answer (score 6):

Write

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{12.5cm}}
```

This requires loading the **array** package (that you're already loading, but other users might not know it).

*Some comments*
Each table has its particular features and it's quite difficult to state "universal rules". In general, however, vertical rules should be avoided as they make the table more difficult to read horizontally.

A generous amount of space between rows can visually separate them in a more pleasant way than with a rule.

Whether centering vertically the description in the first column depends on the table, but I feel it can be distracting.