# Table/tabular problem: vertical centering of long text + increase the row height

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, height

I already checked this post in this site:
[Vertical centering of text within a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20161/vertical-centering-of-text-within-a-table)

What I am asking is quite similar to that question:

1. I want all the cells to be vertically centered. This can be achieved by using the `array` package and the `m{20em}` descriptor.
2. I want to add extra space to the rows; namely, I want the heights of the rows to be larger than default. This can be done by using

   ```
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3em}
   ```

Each of the above two requirements can be easily satisfied separately. However, if I want both effects, problems occur. The cells are not vertically centered, and the table looks really awkward as a whole!

To see the problem, the `\extrarowheight` needs to be set to a large value, `3em` for example.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3em} 

%without the above command, the table looks fine.

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{r m{6em}}

\hline

Item 0 & bla bla \\
\\    
Item 1 & Long description of item 1 blaaaaaa blaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaa blaaaaa blaaa blaaaaaaaaaa \\
\\
Item 2 & blaaaaaaaaaaaa blaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaaaa \\
\\    
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36047/label-in-subcaption-and-customize-cell-size-of-an-array/36067#36067), perhaps it is useful here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,array}
\newcommand{\cellstart}{\rule{0pt}{\heightof{A}+2ex}}
\newcommand{\cellfinish}{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{2ex}}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{r >{\cellstart}m{6em}<{\cellfinish}}
\hline
Item 0 & bla bla \\
\hline
Item 1 & Long description of item 1 blaaaaaa blaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaa blaaaaa blaaa
blaaaaaaaaaa \\
\hline
Item 2 & blaaaaaaaaaaaa blaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaaaa \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Change the `2ex` into what suits you.

However, I find that, in general, such a vertical centering doesn't help the readability of a table, particularly if an entry in the second column is very long.

Comment: Wow! That's great! It works! Thank you very much!
Also thanks to @Thorsten (and maybe other guys) for editing my post!

By the way, the thing I am editing is not really a table; it is actually the cover page of a document; I just want to use the tabular environment to make sure things are well-aligned.